# How do I grab information from HTML to Javascript but that is connected to an API

Tags: javascript, html, api

So I want to connect to this API:

```
<script id="myshiptrackingscript" src="//www.myshiptracking.com/js/widgetApi.js" async defer></script>
```

from here: https://www.myshiptracking.com/more/embed-our-map
I want to make an HTML page where I can input a mmsi (a variable in the code) and display it on the map.

This is what I've got so far:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ship tracker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="mmsi" id="input">
    <input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="ubmit">

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script id="myshiptrackingscript" src="//www.myshiptracking.com/js/widgetApi.js" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and for JAVASCRIPT

```
var mst_width="75%";
var mst_height="350px";
var mst_border="0";
var mst_map_style="simple";
function submit() {
    var mst_mmsi = document.getElementById("input").submit;
}
var mst_show_track="";
var mst_show_info="";
var mst_fleet="";
var mst_lat="";
var mst_lng="";
var mst_zoom="";
var mst_show_names="0";
var mst_scroll_wheel="true";
var mst_show_menu="true";
```

When I submit an input, I get no output from the map... do I have to refresh the map or something?
Here is the code for the HTML:

```
<script>var mst_width="100%";var mst_height="350px";var mst_border="0";var mst_map_style="simple";var 
mst_mmsi="";var mst_show_track="false";var mst_show_info="true";var mst_fleet="";var mst_lat="";var 
mst_lng="";var mst_zoom="";var mst_show_names="0";var mst_scroll_wheel="true";var 
mst_show_menu="true";</script>
<script id="myshiptrackingscript" src="//www.myshiptracking.com/js/widgetApi.js" async defer></script>
```

I grabbed all of that code from the same website: https://www.myshiptracking.com/more/embed-our-map
Click on the link and then click on "get code" to get the exact same code.

Thanks :)
I hope I explained my problem well enough...